# How to run test scripts in parallel machine using Selenium Grid with pom and testNG

Tags: testng, pom.xml, selenium-grid2

Totally i have 50 scripts in my testng.xml, now i want to run 25 in the hub and the remaining 25 in node and both the machine are in same platform windows. here i want to use testNG. and I referred the link
http://www.guru99.com/introduction-to-selenium-grid.html, when i follow this link, i found how to use hub and node but all my script runs in machine node only. how could i split it?

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to understand what is a hub and what is a node.  The hub is not meant to execute the cases but to distribute them to the nodes.  The nodes is where the execution would be.

To the question if you want specific nodes to be used then you need to setup your nodes in a way that the browser version combination is unique (check out the grid2 [wiki](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2#Configuring_the_nodes_by_command_line) )and then you can use the desiredcapabilities object to request for a particular browser and a particular version.